# How to rank people with Adonis Admin on roblox

Tags: lua, admin, roblox

I am creating a Roblox work game, and I am using Davey_Bones's Adonis Admin. There are two ways that I know of to rank someone with that admin system: you could use a command in the game or your could put their user into the script. However, both of those ways rank the players individually. What I want is to link my group to the Admin system, so that if a user is a certain rank in the group, then they can access the commands.

I know how to script rank individuals, and I have tried putting in the script in the format Davey_Bones has provided. This does not work. Here is how I can rank people with the script:

settings.Moderators("username", "username2", "username3")

And here is how I have tried to link the group with that script:

settings.Moderators("groupname:groupid:grouprank")

Answer (score 0):

Adonis has its configuration settings built upon a ModuleScript, so if you'd like to modify the conditions of the settings, then you'll have to edit the variables and tables within the script to tailor the admin system to your specific requirements.

```lua
-- Let's say you want to add a new moderator to the system
-- You would go to the "settings.Ranks" table and find the "Moderators" section
-- Add the new moderator's information to the "Users" list:

settings.Ranks["Moderators"].Users = {
    "ExistingModerator",
    "NewModerator:1234567",
    7654321, -- User ID
    "Group:RobloxDevelopers:3", -- Group ID and rank
    "Item:9876543", -- Item ID
}

-- Now, "NewModerator" with User ID 1234567, User ID 7654321, and those in group "RobloxDevelopers" with rank 3, or owning the item with ID 9876543 will be moderators.

-- You can similarly modify other settings as needed to suit your requirements.
```